# Why I cannot add closure into selector function?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to use selector to call a method which have a closure as parameter. However, I cannot understand why it crashes when the timer start to running.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3, target: self, selector: #selector(demo), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    
    @objc func demo(completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        print("demo")
    }
}
```

Comment: `#selector(demo)` vs `func demo(completion: (() -> Void)? = nil)`, it doesn't have the same signature. Also, print your error message in console when it crashes. Remote the try to rewrite your selector and let autocompletion help you. It should be `demo(completion:)` at least.

Comment: Your selector signature should be `func timerFire(timer: NSTimer) {}` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35102817/swift-nstimer-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-timerfiremethod

Comment: @Larme but if I use a class instead of closure, it will work.
`func demo(completion: ClassA? = nil)` will work

Comment: It does not have error message.

Answer (score 0):

the way you would usually pass on information is by simple using the `userInfo` parameter of the call.

I created a simple example for you that you can paste into a Playground to see it in action:

```
import UIKit

class Foo {

    var timer: Timer?

    init() {
        let userInfo = ["foo": "bar"];
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(fireTimer), userInfo: userInfo, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func fireTimer(timer: Timer) {
        if let userInfo = timer.userInfo as? [String: String], let string = userInfo["foo"] {
            print(string);
        }
    }
}

Foo()
```

You can of course pass on any information you like, I just used strings in my example as one possibility.

Cheers,
Dominic

P.S.: There is a lot of good documentation out there btw, just one example would be https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/117/the-ultimate-guide-to-timer

Comment: `userInfo` is  `Any` type so there is no need to use a dictionary. OP can simply pass the method and then cast to `()->()`. OP can just call it like `(timer.userInfo as? ()->())?()`

Comment: Valid point, @LeoDabus. Big fan of simplification! :)